# How to pass a mysql record to php and be sure that it is UTF-8 encoded

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have a problem, my data is defined as UTF-8 in mysql database.
But when I pass it to the php and format it as JSON I don't get utf-8 signs.

I have put in the header utf-8

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

What can I do next?

Comment: I have tried to print them in javascript, call that php script and I get only data and it is not as it should be

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do next?

You can replace the entire script with this

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
printf('{chr:"%s"}', "\xc6\x94");// Ɣ  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0194/index.htm
```

and then try to use it. If everything works, it means that either your data in the db isnt utf8, or the way you retrieve it doesn't preserve the utf8.

Comment: hi, yes I am getting that sign, I am having problem with croatian alphabet

Comment: issue a `set names utf8` query before any other queries. if it still doesn't work, your data isn't utf8 encoded. note that declaring the column/db whatever as utf8 doesnt *make* it utf8.

Comment: wow.. wait how can I declare it as utf8 then? I was declaring database as utf-8 with the columns.

Comment: you (probably) did declare it as utf8. but if you insert data that isn't utf8, it wont magically become utf8. *YOU* must know the encoding of the strings, and make appropriate conversions. It's not done for you.

Comment: I have added data manually inside. And I can see them correctly

Comment: youre really getting to the point where you should be concluding its time to bite the bullet and do some serious long boring reading on character sets and encodings. you will always struggle with this stuff until you do. but, in an effort to help, ill tell you to send a utf8 content type header on the html page that outputs the html form where this data origionates. do that, and well behaved browsers will send you utf8, and things will probably magically start working. this is about the end of the line for me as far as custom tailored help goes - good luck.